# Application-defined or object-defined error in fill down sections

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create macro that base on information in "cover" sheet, filters data from source file and copy and paste to specific sheet.
Next macro needs to enter formula and fill it down.
When it goes to section:

```
wsDest.Range("BG5").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,K5,M:M,""<>" & M5 & ")=0,""1 supplier"",""Multi"")"
```

I receive error "Application-defined or object-defined error".
How to solve this issue?
Full version of code you can find below

```
Sub FillFormulas()
Dim wbCreatingReports As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wsDestPlant As Worksheet
Dim filterValue As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim destFolder As String
Dim destFile As String

' Open "Creating reports" workbook
Set wbCreatingReports = ThisWorkbook

' Open "_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx" workbook
Set wsSource = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\07 Step ME External Production material_report.xlsx").Worksheets("Local_Currency")

' Set the destination folder path
destFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Final reports\"

' Loop through each file in the destination folder
destFile = Dir(destFolder & "*.xlsx")
Do While destFile <> ""
    ' Open the destination workbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(destFolder & destFile)
    ' Set the destination worksheet (adjust the sheet name if needed)
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("PPF_Local_CY")
    Set wsDestPlant = wbDest.Worksheets("Cover")
    ' Get the filter value from cell C10 in the destination file
    filterValue = wsDestPlant.Range("C10").Value
    
    ' Filter the data in the source file based on the filter value (7th column)
    wsSource.AutoFilterMode = False
    wsSource.Range("A1:BF100000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=filterValue
    
    ' Copy the visible (filtered) data (excluding header) to the destination file
    wsSource.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("A5")
    
    ' Calculate the last row in column BF (excluding header)
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "BF").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Fill down the formula in BG5 (1 supplier or Multi)
    wsDest.Range("BG5").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,K5,M:M,""<>" & M5 & ")=0,""1 supplier"",""Multi"")"
    wsDest.Range("BG5").AutoFill Destination:=wsDest.Range("BG5:BG" & lastRow)
    
    ' Fill down the formula in BH5 (extract text after "/")
    wsDest.Range("BH5").Formula = "=IFERROR(MID($K5,FIND(""/"",$K5)+1,100),"""")"
    wsDest.Range("BH5").AutoFill Destination:=wsDest.Range("BH5:BH" & lastRow)
    
    ' Turn off the filter in the source file
    wsSource.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Close and save the destination workbook
    wbDest.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    ' Get the next file in the folder
    destFile = Dir
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Hint: `Debug.Print "=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,K5,M:M,""<>" & M5 & ")=0,""1 supplier"",""Multi"")"` and inspect the output in the Immediate Window. My guess would be that you need quotes in the formula around the value of `M5`.

Comment: `wsDest.Range("BG5").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,K5,M:M,""<>" & M5 & """)=0,""1 supplier"",""Multi"")"`

Comment: `wsDest.Range("BG5").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,K5,M:M,""<>" & M5 & """)=0,""1 supplier"",""Multi"")"` worked. Thanks!